# Generate all permutations in go

Tags: algorithm, go

I am looking for a way to generate all possible permutations of a list of elements. Something similar to [python's](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations) `itertools.permutations(arr)`

```
permutations ([])
[]

permutations ([1])
[1]

permutations ([1,2])
[1, 2]
[2, 1]

permutations ([1,2,3])
[1, 2, 3]
[1, 3, 2]
[2, 1, 3]
[2, 3, 1]
[3, 1, 2]
[3, 2, 1]
```

With the difference that I do not care whether permutations would be generated on demand (like a generator in python) or all together. I also do not care whether they will be lexicographically sorted. All I need is to somehow get these `n!` permutations.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

There are a lot of the algorithms that generate [permutations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation#Algorithms_to_generate_permutations). One of the easiest I found is [Heap's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap%27s_algorithm):

> It generates each permutation from the previous one by choosing a pair
>   of elements to interchange.

The idea and a pseudocode that prints the permutations one after another is outlined in the above link. Here is my implementation of the algorithm which returns all permutations

```
func permutations(arr []int)[][]int{
    var helper func([]int, int)
    res := [][]int{}

    helper = func(arr []int, n int){
        if n == 1{
            tmp := make([]int, len(arr))
            copy(tmp, arr)
            res = append(res, tmp)
        } else {
            for i := 0; i < n; i++{
                helper(arr, n - 1)
                if n % 2 == 1{
                    tmp := arr[i]
                    arr[i] = arr[n - 1]
                    arr[n - 1] = tmp
                } else {
                    tmp := arr[0]
                    arr[0] = arr[n - 1]
                    arr[n - 1] = tmp
                }
            }
        }
    }
    helper(arr, len(arr))
    return res
}
```

and here is an example of how to use it ([Go playground](https://play.golang.org/p/Ulyo1H2Bii)):

```
arr := []int{1, 2, 3}
fmt.Println(permutations(arr))
[[1 2 3] [2 1 3] [3 2 1] [2 3 1] [3 1 2] [1 3 2]]
```

One thing to notice that the permutations are not sorted lexicographically (as you have seen in `itertools.permutations`). If for some reason you need it to be sorted, one way I have found it is to generate them from a [factorial number system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial_number_system) (it is described in `permutation section` and allows to quickly find n-th lexicographical permutation).

**P.S.** you can also take a look at others people code [here](https://github.com/fighterlyt/permutation) and [here](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Permutations#Go)

Answer (score 18):

Here's code that iterates over all permutations without generating them all first. The slice `p` keeps the intermediate state as offsets in a Fisher-Yates shuffle algorithm. This has the nice property that the zero value for `p` describes the identity permutation.

```
package main

import "fmt"

func nextPerm(p []int) {
    for i := len(p) - 1; i >= 0; i-- {
        if i == 0 || p[i] < len(p)-i-1 {
            p[i]++
            return
        }
        p[i] = 0
    }
}

func getPerm(orig, p []int) []int {
    result := append([]int{}, orig...)
    for i, v := range p {
        result[i], result[i+v] = result[i+v], result[i]
    }
    return result
}

func main() {
    orig := []int{11, 22, 33}
    for p := make([]int, len(orig)); p[0] < len(p); nextPerm(p) {
        fmt.Println(getPerm(orig, p))
    }
}
```

Comment: Excellent implementation (+1 from me). Thank you for another algorithm. Just one minor bug: it panics on empty slice. You can also add that the permutations are in lexicographical order.

Comment: I've turned this into a library for a personal project. I turned the functions into methods, fixed handling the empty slice, and added the option to read from a channel. [Have a look](https://gist.github.com/schwern/93f7d93c1c80f8720e6de85bdc92096f). Would you mind if I published this open source?

Comment: +1 fastest algo for lexicographic ordered permutation afaik!  Could be sped up by additional ~10% if getPerm() line 1 is changed to result:=make([]int, len(orig)); copy(result, orig); (go1.10.3 darwin/amd64) The reason is that append is calling repeatedly for reallocation to allocate additional memory according to the exploitation of the append source (append is time critical).

Answer (score 2):

```
var res [][]int
func permute(nums []int) [][]int {
    res=make([][]int,0)
    n:=len(nums)
    var backTrack func(int)
    backTrack=func(first int){
        if first == n{
            temp:=make([]int, n)
            copy(temp,nums)
            res = append(res, temp)
        }
        for i:=first;i<n;i++{
            nums[first],nums[i] = nums[i],nums[first]
            backTrack(first+1)
            nums[first],nums[i] = nums[i],nums[first]
        }
    }
  
    backTrack(0)
    return res
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had a reference to an array, then I've did a few changes in your example:

```
func generateIntPermutations(array []int, n int, result *[][]int) {
    if n == 1 {
        dst := make([]int, len(array))
        copy(dst, array[:])
        *result = append(*result, dst)
    } else {
        for i := 0; i < n; i++ {
            generateIntPermutations(array, n-1, result)
            if n%2 == 0 {
                // Golang allow us to do multiple assignments
                array[0], array[n-1] = array[n-1], array[0]
            } else {
                array[i], array[n-1] = array[n-1], array[i]
            }
        }
    }
}
numbers := []int{0, 1, 2}
var result [][]int
generateIntPermutations(numbers, len(numbers), &result)

// result -> [[0 1 2] [1 0 2] [2 1 0] [1 2 0] [2 0 1] [0 2 1]]
```

Comment: Thanks @derricw, I forgot to insert that copy in the function. My original function used a slice of strings, so I didn't need to copy the array at that point. I will try to find a nicer way in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Another Working code

```
package permutations

import "fmt"

func AllPermutation(a []int) {
    var res [][]int
    calPermutation(a, &res, 0)
    fmt.Println(res)
}
func calPermutation(arr []int, res *[][]int, k int) {
    for i := k; i < len(arr); i++ {
        swap(arr, i, k)
        calPermutation(arr, res, k+1)
        swap(arr, k, i)
    }
    if k == len(arr)-1 {
        r := make([]int, len(arr))
        copy(r, arr)
        *res = append(*res, r)
        return
    }
}
func swap(arr []int, i, k int) {
    arr[i], arr[k] = arr[k], arr[i]
}
//result [[1 2 3] [1 3 2] [2 1 3] [2 3 1] [3 2 1] [3 1 2]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another variation:

```golang
// heap algorithm
func permutations(arr []int, l int, p [][]int) [][]int {
  if l == 1 { p = append(p, append([]int{}, arr...)) }
  for i := 0 ; i < l ; i++ {
    p = permutations(arr, l-1, p)
    if l % 2 == 1 {
      arr[0], arr[l-1] = arr[l-1], arr[0]
    } else {
      arr[i], arr[l-1] = arr[l-1], arr[i]
    }
  }
  return p
}
```

Answer (score 0):

*Permutation code using simple algorithm in golang*

```
package main

import "fmt"

func permute(arr[] int, start int, end int) {
        if start == end {
                fmt.Println(arr)
                return
        }
        for i:=start;i<end;i++ {
                arr[i],arr[start] = arr[start],arr[i]
                permute(arr,start+1,end)
                arr[i],arr[start] = arr[start],arr[i]
        }
}

func main() {
        arr := []int{1,2,3}
        end := len(arr)
        start := 0
        permute(arr,start,end)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **Iterium** package for this task: https://github.com/mowshon/iterium

Example code for your question:

```golang
permutations := iterium.Permutations([]string{"A", "B", "C", "D"}, 2)
toSlice, _ := permutations.Slice()

fmt.Println("Total:", permutations.Count())
fmt.Println(toSlice)
```

Result:

```
Total: 12

[
    [A, B] [A, C] [A, D] [B, A] [B, C] [B, D]
    [C, B] [C, A] [C, D] [D, B] [D, C] [D, A]
]
```

Answer (score 0):

````
import "fmt"

func permutation(arr []int, pos int, size int) [][]int {
    var result = make([][]int, 0)

    if pos == size {
        temp := make([]int, size)
        copy(temp, arr)
        result = append(result, temp)
    } else {
        for i := pos; i < size; i++ {
            arr[i], arr[pos] = arr[pos], arr[i]
            output := permutation(arr, pos+1, size)
            result = append(result, output...)
            arr[i], arr[pos] = arr[pos], arr[i]
        }
    }
    return result
}
func main() {
    arr := []int{1, 2, 3}
    fmt.Println(permutation(arr, 0, len(arr)))
}```
````

Comment: Thank you for your interest in contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This question already has quite a few answers—including one that has been extensively validated by the community. Are you certain your approach hasn’t been given previously? **If so, it would be useful to explain how your approach is different, under what circumstances your approach might be preferred, and/or why you think the previous answers aren’t sufficient.** Can you kindly [edit] your answer to offer an explanation?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function using generics of the accepted answer:

```
func permutations[T any](arr []T) [][]T {
    var helper func([]T, int)
    res := make([][]T, 0)

    helper = func(arr []T, n int) {
        if n == 1 {
            tmp := make([]T, len(arr))
            copy(tmp, arr)
            res = append(res, tmp)
        } else {
            for i := 0; i < n; i++ {
                helper(arr, n-1)
                if n%2 == 1 {
                    tmp := arr[i]
                    arr[i] = arr[n-1]
                    arr[n-1] = tmp
                } else {
                    tmp := arr[0]
                    arr[0] = arr[n-1]
                    arr[n-1] = tmp
                }
            }
        }
    }
    helper(arr, len(arr))
    return res
}
```