# Unexpected behavior when passing a pointer to a slice in go

Tags: go

The following go program is supposed to generate all permutations of a slice of integers:

```
package main
import "fmt"

func permute(nums []int) [][]int {
    var res [][]int
    var s []int
    permuteHlp(&res, nums, 0, s)
    return res
}

func permuteHlp(res *[][]int, nums []int, i int, s []int) {
    if i == len(nums) {
        *res = append(*res, s)
        return
    }

    for j := i; j < len(nums); j++ {
        s = append(s, nums[j])
        nums[i], nums[j] = nums[j], nums[i]
        permuteHlp(res, nums, i+1, s)
        s = s[:len(s)-1]
        nums[i], nums[j] = nums[j], nums[i]
    }
}

func main() {
    x := []int{1,2,3,4}
    y := permute(x)

    fmt.Println(y)
}
```

The output is unexpected

```
[[1 2 4 3] [1 2 4 3] [1 3 4 2] [1 3 4 2] [1 4 2 3] [1 4 2 3] [2 1 4 3] [2 1 4 3] [2 3 4 1] [2 3 4 1] [2 4 1 3] [2 4 1 3] [3 2 4 1] [3 2 4 1] [3 1 4 2] [3 1 4 2] [3 4 2 1] [3 4 2 1] [4 2 1 3] [4 2 1 3] [4 3 1 2] [4 3 1 2] [4 1 2 3] [4 1 2 3]]
```

I don't understand what is wrong here. I would appreciate any help.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no need for a pointer to the slice since slices are pointers themselves. "a slice is a reference to a contiguous segment of an array.", [reference](https://hackernoon.com/golang-slice-and-append-e18498cf924a).

The strange behavior you're seeing is because you're using append, when a slice grows beyond its capacity it's required to create a new slice with increased capacity and copy all the contents of the original one (this is what append does behind the scenes), hence new slice is no longer pointing to the original underlying array.

Instead of modifying the incoming parameter, I suggest returning the slice as a return value for the function.

```
func permute(nums []int) [][]int {
   res := permuteHlp(nums, 0, new([]int))
   return res
}
```

I recommend you read the blog post in golang.org about slices internals, [here](https://blog.golang.org/go-slices-usage-and-internals)

---

Edit:

I add a refactor, taking the algorithm from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30226442/5883716).

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"  
)

func permutations(arr []int)[][]int{
    var helper func([]int, int)
    res := [][]int{}

    helper = func(arr []int, n int){
        if n == 1{
            tmp := make([]int, len(arr))
            copy(tmp, arr)
            res = append(res, tmp)
        } else {
            for i := 0; i < n; i++{
                helper(arr, n - 1)
                if n % 2 == 1{
                    tmp := arr[i]
                    arr[i] = arr[n - 1]
                    arr[n - 1] = tmp
                } else {
                    tmp := arr[0]
                    arr[0] = arr[n - 1]
                    arr[n - 1] = tmp
                }
            }
        }
    }
    helper(arr, len(arr))
    return res
}

func main() {
    x := []int{1,2,3,4}
    d := permutations(x)
    fmt.Print(d)
}
```

Generally you won't want to have a pointer to a slice, instead, return a new one from the function, another thing to comment on, try not to use recursion if possible as golang doesn't have tail call optimization, and its loops perform amazingly. Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you for your response. I'm afraid, I am still a bit lost since
*res = append(*res, s)
does update the slice. No?

Comment: I'm editing the answer with a proposed refactor explaining a little bit

Comment: @JF-Sebastian I just added a refactor, anyways I would recommend you read more about pointers and slices, since they are pretty tricky at the beginning. Generally you would use pointers with structs, and in some rare cases with maps.

Answer (score 2):

You're passing around a pointer to the the same slice. In the end you wind up with a bunch of pointers to the same slice in your results, so of course all the values will be identical - it's the same slice printed over and over.

It's also worth noting that a pointer to a slice is rarely what you want, as slices already contain a pointer to the underlying array.