# How to get some unique random items from a slice

Tags: arrays, algorithm, go, unique, slice

In this code

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math/rand"
)

func main() {
    rand.Seed(86)
    items := []string{"aaa", "bbb", "ccc", "ddd", "eee", "fff", "ggg"}
    item1 := items[rand.Intn(len(items))]
    item2 := items[rand.Intn(len(items))]
    item3 := items[rand.Intn(len(items))]
    fmt.Print(item1 + " ")
    fmt.Print(item2 + " ")
    fmt.Print(item3)
    fmt.Println()
}
```

[playground](https://play.golang.org/p/G6uo4JP7PhE)

I want to get three different items from list `items`. But this method will return same data sometimes as everytime is random like

```
bbb ddd ddd
```

How to get unique data and loop all the patterns?

Such as

```
aaa bbb ccc
aaa bbb ddd
aaa bbb eee
aaa bbb fff
aaa bbb ggg
bbb ccc ddd
bbb ccc eee
bbb ccc fff
bbb ccc ggg
ccc ddd eee
ccc ddd fff
ccc ddd ggg
ddd eee fff
ddd eee ggg
eee fff ggg
```

---

## Solution

Use this [code](https://play.golang.org/p/4AASL-BjXrg) can get all the permutations, but some of them returned same data, just changed index.

Comment: The correct language might help you find answers already out there: You want a random permutation of the slice.  However at the end of your question, it looks like you want *every* permutation, and you don't care about randomness. Which is it?

Comment: This code will return you random items, but it does not guarantee all possible permutations. Also, the playground runs with a fixed seed, so it is not exactly random. Try  using `rand.Seed` and run it locally.

Comment: @HymnsForDisco I want 3 different data every time, add want to get all the pattens in the slice.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Generate all permutations in go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30226438/generate-all-permutations-in-go)

Comment: @BurakSerdar I updated code in playground.

Comment: @HymnsForDisco I added `Solution` to the end of the question. I tried that, just a little more patterns.

Comment: I added answer for it, you can try that and it's easy one from the solution you added,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use static value on rand package seeds and first you need to read this :

*Seed uses the provided seed value to initialize the default Source to a deterministic state. If Seed is not called, the generator behaves as if seeded by Seed(1). Seed values that have the same remainder when divided by 2³¹-1 generate the same pseudo-random sequence. Seed, unlike the Rand.Seed method, is safe for concurrent use.*

So seeds are static value when you provide init value.

You need to do something like this :

```
rand.Seed(time.Now().UnixNano())
```