# How to make combination sets of 15 words in go

Tags: algorithm, go, combinations

I have a sets of words with 15 length long, i want to make all possibilities words order.
First word have to came with all other words from 2th to 15th and with second word with 1th + 3th to 15th(second number should be imported in 15 indexes except of second index).
it's really hard to explain what i want exactly but i hope example help.

> Example with 4 number(for simplicity):

```
1 2 3 4
1 2 4 3
1 3 2 4
1 3 4 2
1 4 2 3
1 4 3 2
2 1 3 4
2 1 4 3
2 3 1 4
2 3 4 1
same with 3,4 at the first....
```

> ordering sets is not important at all but good, it's more important to make all the possibilities with all words with total length of 15.

My problem is with this algorithm not exactly with the code but, thanks for any helpful algorithm or code.

Comment: I believe you're looking for [permutations](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30226442/6438819) rather than combinations.

Comment: How will you use these permutations? For 15 words, there are over 1.3 trillion unique orderings.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://play.golang.org/p/9oOpBM1NtLC) is a solution with a recursive function. You can change the type of "elements" parameter according to your situation.

This might be suboptimal in terms of performance, but it should work correctly.

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    results := permutations([]int{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, 3)
    for _, perm := range results {
        fmt.Println(perm)
    }
    fmt.Println(len(results)) // should print 5 * 4 * 3 = 60
}

func permutations(elements []int, length int) [][]int {
    var results [][]int
    var perm = make([]int, length)      // to write each permutation
    used := make([]bool, len(elements)) // used[i] indicates whether i-th element is already used

    var dfs func(currentIndex, depth int)
    dfs = func(currentIndex, depth int) {
        perm[length-depth] = elements[currentIndex]
        if depth == 1 {
            result := make([]int, length)
            copy(result, perm)
            results = append(results, result)
            return
        }
        used[currentIndex] = true
        for i := range elements {
            if used[i] {
                continue
            }
            dfs(i, depth-1)
        }
        used[currentIndex] = false
    }
    // start from all elements
    for i := range elements {
        dfs(i, length)
    }
    return results
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Heap’s algorithm:
https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap%27s_algorithm

Pseudocode is in the article.

There are probably many other algorithms to solve your problem, but this is one way to do it.